# Как более грамотно отправлять форму

Tags: jquery, ajax, form

serialize() или val() ?

Comment: Вопрос задан не корректно. 

 - **.serialize()** - возвратит строку, с именами и значениями выбранных элементов формы
 - **val()** - возвращает значение атрибута value у выбранного элемента формы

Назначения методов разные, а чего хотите добиться вы?

Answer (score 1):

Если через AJAX то

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type : 'post',
    data : $('form').serialize(),
    success : function(data) {
        // получаем ответ в <div id="response"></div>
        $('#response').html(data);
    }
});
```

Если в форме есть select или radio то через .val() отправить не получится
Если надо просто инициировать запрос то тогда

```
$('form').submit();
```

Если нет jQuery то

```
window.form[0].submit();
```